# Is there a way to make multiple html5 filereader.onload events fire sequentially?

Tags: javascript

I am using the html5 filereader API to get photos locally without the user having to upload them.

In browsers that support it I am allowing multiple selections so I am looping through the selected files and performing a function on each one (TC.editor.renderSlide()) as shown below:

```
 handlePhotoUploads: function(event) {
    var self = this;
    TC.dialog.destroy();
    var files = event.target.files;
    var count = files.length + TC.editor.cache.slides.length;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var index = TC.editor.getNewSlidesIndex();
        TC.editor.addNewSlide('photo', index);
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            var slideindex = index;
            return function(e) {
                TC.editor.renderSlide(slideindex, e.target.result, 'internal', count);
            };
        })(f);
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
},
```

The problem is that the TC.editor.renderSlide() function can take a significant amount of time to perform (performs canvas and DOM manipulations) so when dealing with 8 or so large image files the browser gets locked for a substantial amount of time.  Even the 'processing gif's stop animating during this period.

Is there any way to ensure that each reader.onload event fires only after the previous one has completed? This way the user would be given regular progress updates by seeing the result of each call to TC.editor.renderSlide() individually rather than the current situation which locks the browser while everything is being processed?

I have tried adding a simple setTimeout to renderSlide() to no avail?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use a for `loop`. Start processing the next file from inside the `load` callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onload` events *do fire sequentially*, the handler is not executed while an other one is currently processed ("JS is single-threaded"). This of course does not count when you *start* some asynchronous processing (timeouts, animations, file loads) in a handler.

In that case, you will need to manually handle the sequential processing. It's easy using a queue of waiting processes which are executed when one is finished:

```
var waiting = [];
// …create many parallel loaders, and on each:
    ….onevent = execute;

function execute(e) {
    if (waiting.active)
        waiting.push(e);
    else {
        waiting.active = true
        // do something that takes its time, supplying a
          … function callback(ready) {
            waiting.active = false;
            if (waiting.length)
                execute(waiting.shift()); // go on with next
          }
    }
}
```

However, it seems to me that not `renderSlide` is causing the problems, but that you instantiate so many `FileReader`s at the same time. Make them start loading files one after the other, by turning your for-loop into an asynchronously called "recursive" function:

```
var files = […]
(function handle(i) {
     if (i >= files.length) return;
     // create loader
     ….onevent = function(e) {
          // do processing, and then call
          handle(i+1);
          // or call that from another callback if you want to do async
          // processing, like "renderSlide"
     };
})(0);
```

Comment: Thanks to all here really... I have actually done as both yourself, Ianzz and Felix suggested.  I had made the reader calls recursive and also broken the renderSlide() function down with setTimeouts.  The results is very responsive and exactly as intended.  Thanks to all. :)

Comment: Hey, I've had not even finished my answer :-) Glad to have helped

Comment: Indeed, i've just seen your edit! :)  The second I realized where I had gone wrong I got straight into re-coding it... Was done in less than a minute and what a difference!  Your answer now is fantastic and although the code differs due to my personal app specific structure, is pretty much the same approach I took. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The events *do* fire sequentially. Javascript is single-threaded, so while one of your event handlers is executing, no other event will fire, and also your browser`*` remain be unresponsive, as its single thread is occupied by running your Javascript event handler. It is not enough to execute your entire `renderSlide()` in a `setTimeout`, because the browser will still be locked for the duration of the entire `renderSlide()` execution. You will need to break the actual logic *inside* `renderSlide()` into separate chunks *each of which* you can postpone using `setTimeout(chunk, 1)`, giving the browser a little breathing room to maintain responsiveness.

`*` Actually, it might not be the entire browser that is locked up — it could be just one tab or a group of related tabs running in a single thread. Actual browser architectures differ.