# JavaScript "Out of Memory" Error with FileReader in a for loop

Tags: javascript, out-of-memory, filereader

I have a function where I should read up to 300 files (JSON each one with aprox. 20MB) and send it over a node.js server to a influxdb.

My problem now is that when I execute my code with 15-25 files everything is working fine but when I select 200 or more I get really quick a "Out of Memory" exception from the browser.

I think that it is the "new FileReader" inside of the for loop but when I move it outside it won't work anything.

so here is my code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
      //console.log("a---------------------------");
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = await onReaderLoad;
      reader.readAsText(fileList[i]);
      let tempData = "";
      async function onReaderLoad(event) {
        //console.log("b------");
        //data1 = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
        tempData = event.target.result; //send as text is much faster to the server as as parsed JSON
        //console.log("c------");
        await writeTheData(tempData);
        //console.log("d------");
      }
    }
```

and here the code of the "writeTheData" function which is above the other code in the .js file

```
  function writeTheData(tempData) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:7000/api/writeJSONtoInfluxDB",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: tempData,
      success: function (data) {
        console.warn("uploading and import data: " + data);
      },
    }).then((response) => response.data);
  }
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: what is the purpse of await here: `reader.onload = await onReaderLoad;` ? i think you should queue those files and stream them instead of opening 200 post transactions in paralel

Comment: @Estradiaz i want to wait that there is everything finished (write to the database with the other function) but i see now that this is async working and not sync. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Estradiaz so and whats the best way to queue 300 JSONs and stream them? all 300 JSON concat to one textfile and then make a POST to the server? or are there better solutions? i can also use jquery

Comment: A common pattern is to use some sort of queue e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167756/is-there-a-way-to-make-multiple-html5-filereader-onload-events-fire-sequentially